# Division formula in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[Sample File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgAKX.jpg)I have looked through the web and still cant find a solution. The best is this thread -https://superuser.com/questions/1083082/division-formula-in-excel

But the underlying questions are still unanswered...
How to keep the denominator of a division formula as absolute reference and making it dynamic at the same time?

I am starting to wonder if its even possible...

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by division formula and what do you mean by absolute and dynamic at the same time? Perhaps you could make the denominator a named range.

Comment: I have a similar problem as posted in the link above. I would not want to hard code the denominator as I may have new data everyday. Is there a way for the denominator to change accordingly? E.g. today the row may be at B65, but tmr it may be at B75.

Comment: Then use relative addressing...

Comment: Would that help me divide all the range with the same denominator for the respective days? E.g. B53/B65 and B54/B65 for the first day while B53/B75 and B54/B75 for the second day. Note that I wouldnt know what will be the last row. Thus the need for a dynamic code...

Comment: Until you show exactly what you are working with, how can we help? The question you link to has an accepted answer which seems relevant.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear questions. Basically I have tried using something like RC2/RC2.End(xlDown) so that my denominator always follows the last used cell in column B. But it returns me an error message of runtime 1004 object unidentified. In the linked solution, the denominator was hard coded at B65 which is not going to be sustainable since my data set changes everyday. Thank you all for your time and effort I really appreciate it alot.

Comment: May you provide the data you're working with and the result expected, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your denominator "follow" the last cell value in Column B, you can use this Array formula 
 in your denominator to pluck the value out as the ROW number in which it is varies : =INDEX(B$1:B$25,MAX(IF(B$1:B$25>0,ROW(B$1:B$25),"")),1).This formula can be varied in many ways if I did not understand your intent. Enter with Ctrl, Shift, Enter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried and this is 1 step closer to what I am looking for.

Comment: I will try to be clearer. Basically I will receive a report from another department. After doing a pivot table, I will get a format that is similar to the data set in the link above (sales number in column B). I wish to express each sales number as a percentage of the 'TOTAL Sales'. The challenge is 1. finding the last row and get the total sales (due to varying number of rows everyday), 2. Fixing total sales as the denominator, 3. Divide every sales number by Total sales to get a percentage view

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way mathematically. You do not need to "find" the last cell in order to get a percentage. Put this in C2 :  = (B2/Sum($B$2:$B20000))*100 and then fill down. This will give each person's percentage of total sales.

Comment: As a further side note to your already answered question, I later realized that we all took the long way home. Excel itself has a function just for this, your problem. It is the  PERCENTRANK.INC function. That will give you the same accurate results..

Answer (score 0):

=(B2/SUM(B:B))*100 and drag down